# Start a program at the start of xfce

Tags: xfce

I've installed volumeicon-alsa, I'd like to add in the panel the icon without typing each time that I switch on the computer in the terminal `volumeicon` but I'd like to let it start at the start of XFCE, how can I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Settings` menu locate and start `Session and Startup` (or start it from the terminal window with `xfce4-session-settings` command). Then go to `Applicaton Autostart` tab and click on `Add` button. In the `Add application` dialog provide a name and a command you like to execute upon log in. Click `OK` button. Then close the `Session and Startup` application.

Enjoy!